# Unable to cast List into IList

Tags: c#, casting

I am trying to cast List into IList, but unable to cast. Compiler allow me to cast it only into IEnumerable:

```
//Not allowed, why?
public override IList<ILineEntity> Lines
{
   get { return _PharamaLines ?? (_PharamaLines = new List<PharamaLine>()); }
}

//Allowed
public override IEnumerable<ILineEntity> Lines
{
   get { return _PharamaLines ?? (_PharamaLines = new List<PharamaLine>()); }
}
```

`PharamaLine` is of type `ILineEntity`.

> Error: Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<FW.PharamaLine>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IList<Foundation.Interfaces.ILineEntity>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What is `PharamaLine`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman does it matters?

Comment: @PatrickHofman `ILineEntity`

Comment: @NoIdeaForName: Yes, a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is:

`IList<T>` is *invariant*, while `IEnumerable<out T>` is *covariant* (the `out` keyword).

If you define a `List<PharamaLine>`, you basically state that you can only add `PharmaLine` objects to the list, but you could add *different* `ILineEntity` objects to a `IList<ILineEntity>`, and that would break the contract.

Suppose you have some class `OtherLine : ILineEntity`. Imagine this code were valid:

```
var list = new List<PharmaLine>();
var list2 = (IList<ILineEntity>)list; // Invalid!
list2.Add(new OtherLine()); // This should work if the cast were valid
```

This works for an enumerable, since a sequence of `PharmaLine` is *always* a valid sequence of `ILineEntity` (covariance).

Note that you can also use a `IReadOnlyList<out T>` which is also covariant but lacks the methods that let you modify the list.

Comment: Then what should I do, if I want to add `PharamaLine` in `Lines`? I mean which contract?

Comment: You can use a `List<ILineEntity>` **if** this is what your code is supposed to mean.

Comment: Or you can use a `IReadOnlyList<ILineEntity>`

Comment: How to define this `Line` property in abstract base class then?

Comment: Sorry but I can't answer that since I don't know your design...